# How to multiply two iterators and return the product to a thrust::reduce algorithm?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have this reduce_by_key working fine, except I want to multiply dv_Vals with another vector (dv_Active) that contains 0 or 1 values so that the resultant product is a new iterator with either a value from dv_Vals or 0.

```
thrust::reduce_by_key(
            //dv_Keys = { 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 }
            dv_Keys.begin(),
            dv_Keys.end(),
            thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                dv_Vals.begin(), //I want to multiply each element of dv_Vals with each element of dv_Active here.
                dv_Map.begin()
            ),
            thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
            dv_NewVals.begin()
        );
```

My attempt at rewriting the reduce_by_key (replaced dv_Vals with make_transform_iterator) gives me errors:

```
thrust::reduce_by_key(
            //dv_Keys = { 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 }
            dv_Keys.begin(),
            dv_Keys.end(),
            thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
                        thrust::make_tuple(
                            dv_Vals.begin(),
                            dv_Active.begin()
                        )
                    ),
                    _1 * _2 //My attempt to multiply the value in dv_Vals with dv_Active.
                ),
                dv_Map.begin()
            ),
            thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
            dv_NewVals.begin()
        );
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to multiply two vectors within a reduce?

Comment: @RobertCrovella but the transform is on the input, not the output?

Comment: The actual problem is using the placeholders together with a zip_iterator/tuple as input. `thrust::make_zip_function(_1 * _2)` compiles (it's kinda black magic to me). And using a device lambda also [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/n9TWh714o). Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time (in this case the encasing function and includes like in my godbolt link would be enough).

Comment: Also be careful with the `permutation_iterator`, it will not only add a layer of indirection but also make memory coalescing impossible (assuming a non-trivial mapping)  which has a big performance impact. In many cases one doesn't have a choice here, as reordering the elements is even more costly, but if you access the data multiple times in the permuted ordering, it might be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in

```cpp
thrust::make_transform_iterator(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
        thrust::make_tuple(
            dv_Vals.begin(),
            dv_Active.begin()
        )
    ),
    _1 * _2 // does **not** compile!
)
```

The `zip_iterator` gives you a tuple, i.e. a single argument. `_1 * _2` generates a functor template with two arguments (a "binary functor"). This can be solved using the `zip_function` feature which wraps the functor with another one (a "unary functor") unpacking the tuple:

```cpp
#include <thrust/zip_function.h>
/ ...
thrust::make_transform_iterator(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
        thrust::make_tuple(
            dv_Vals.begin(),
            dv_Active.begin()
        )
    ),
    thrust::make_zip_function(_1 * _2)
)
```

Alternatively you can use a device lambda or functor which uses `thrust::get`:

```cpp
thrust::make_transform_iterator(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
        thrust::make_tuple(
            dv_Vals.begin(),
            dv_Active.begin()
        )
    ),
    [] __device__ (auto val_and_active) {
        return thrust::get<0>(val_and_active) * thrust::get<1>(val_and_active);
    }
)
```

`nvcc` needs the `--extended-lambda` flag for this to compile.

Something like `thrust::get<0>(_1) * thrust::get<1>(_1)` doesn't work at the time of writing, although I believe it could be implemented in Thrust by specializing `thrust::get` if someone asks for it (posts an issue). Although the maintainers might not see a point to it due to the existence of `thrust::make_zip_function` which lets you write nicer looking code (without overhead?).